# Sharepoint 2010 REST webservices

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

We are developing HTML5 app which connects to Sharepoint 2013 using REST webservice.
for testing purpose we have setup Sharepoint 2010.

So my query : Is there any huge difference between Sharepoint 2010 and Sharepoint 2013 in terms of REST webservices.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is a backward-compatibility from SP2013 to 2010, but you will be loosing huge amount of features from SP2013 by using old rest services. Also, these webservices may become deprecated with any upcoming version - it might be important especially if you're targeting Office 365 as well.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013 /_vti_bin/ services is deprecated. /_api/ is a new entrypoint. REST services in SharePoint 2013 supports OData, HTTP GET, PUT and POST verbs. And its cover much more then ever:

- User Profiles (no need to use User Profiles ASMX for remote calls)
- Search (no need to use Search.ASMX for remote calls)
- Taxonomy
- Feeds
- Publishing
- Sharing
- Workflow
- E-Discovery
- IRM
- Analytics
- BCS